# Web service in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, xsd, wsdl

Previously I used web services sample from console application, but I don't have much knowledge in that in terms of understanding in xsd and wsdl.

I would like to consume the complex web service to understand xsd and wsdl.

When goggling found some sample free web services, they have provided wsdl file, and service url. I am able to add the web reference in C#, but not understanding how and which method to call, could any body can provide sample code to consume?

- Service URL: `http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL`
- Web method : `GetWeatherResponse`

When I add the service reference from the application I am able to see the these classes.

```
  input1, input2, input3, input4, 
  output1, output2, output3, output4,
  ArticleType, ArticlePtServiceClient, ArticlePTservicechannel
```

but I'm not able to view `GetWeatherResponse()`

From the wsdl file can i get to know from which class object we can call the web method?

Theoretical understanding is we can find the web method based on the wsdl.
Eagerly awaiting positive responses. Expecting sample code to call this web method from the web service.As well as requesting you to some references to better understand complex type xsd's.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not how this site works. You show some effort (like what you tried) and people will help you to succeed.

Comment: Expecting people to supply you with sample code is a good, and quick, way of getting your post closed. No one is here to write code for you, without you putting forth a little effort on your own.

Comment: @nvoigt: sure i will update what i have done also

Comment: @Randy:sorry for not placing that information,added the observed behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of R&D understand littele things regarding Web service and WCF.

The only solution is We have to create stub to test in local environment.

Createing stub :

SVCUTIL

still need to learn more, more questions are there in mind. will update here for our reference.